# Mediapipe as dll on unsupported language

Tags: mediapipe

Mediapipe exist for python or js, but I would like to use it with unsupported native language. Usualy I use dll and export function.

With the current source of mediapipe, does it's possible to generate a dll ?

I try to generate dll from py but I got an error, don't know if I need to do it to all mediapipe files ?

```
python -m nuitka --module my_mediapipe_module.py
```

I identify one module to use, `selfie_segmentation` and only two method, `SelfieSegmentation (__init__)` and `process`.

That look not so difficult, but I don't really know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: what is this unsupported language ?